Peugeot 107 losing power and over-revving
My Peugeot 107 lacks power and over-revs when I accelerate. There are no warning symbols on the dash and no obvious noises coming from the engine. It idles fine, does not stall and shows no other symptoms. Any ideas please?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say it over revs, are you saying it gets higher in the RPM range before shifting?

If it's a manual gearbox the clutch could be slipping when power is applied. If so, I think there is a cable adjustment possible (see YouTube), or at worst, clutch replacement if the plates are too worn.

PAULSTER2, no, I have to accelerate harder after changing or when going uphill

Make sure you don't drive with your left foot resting on the clutch pedal, which can cause it to slip, and/or wear prematurely.
